# Equality operator not working `c`

Tags: c, pointers, equality

I am trying to count how many times a `.` appear in a single string passed in by the command line.

calling `myprog "this...is a test."`

returns `The count is 0`?

What am I doing wrong here?

**Note:** *I know this code may look odd but is for education purposes*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int len = strlen(argv[1]);
  char *d = malloc (strlen(argv[1])+1);
  strcpy(d,argv[1]);
  char *p=d;
  int count;
  count=0;  
  while(*p){
    if (*p ==','){
      count++;
    }
    *p++;
  }

  printf("The count is: %d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Watch out for memory leaks!  You should remember to free everything you malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has quite a few...oddities. It's a little hard to guess which are intentional and which aren't, so let's go through it line by line and see what's there.

```
int len = strlen(argv[1]);
char *d = malloc (strlen(argv[1])+1);
strcpy(d,argv[1]);
```

It appears you probably intended to *use* `len` at some point, but as it stands right now, you get `len`, then re-compute the same value to use it. Presumably you intended something more like:

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
char *d = malloc(len+1);
strcpy(d, argv[1]);
```

I'd note, however, that there's really no reason to do any of this. Since you're just trying to examine the contents, you might as well just use `argv[1]` directly (or create another pointer to the same place and use that).

```
char *p=d;
```

This creates another pointer to the same location as `d`. You didn't really need `d` to start with, and you don't really need this either, but it's fairly harmless.

```
int count;
count=0;
```

I'd (strongly) prefer to see `count` initialized rather than left uninitialized, then assigned a value afterwards. Since there's no possibility of its being negative, I'd probably also make it an unsigned type: `size_t count = 0;`

```
while(*p){
  if (*p ==','){
    count++;
  }
  *p++;
}
```

As others have already pointed out, you're comparing to the wrong value here. I'd also note, however, that when you have an initialization, a test, and an "increment" operation of some sort, you're almost certainly better off using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

In addition, you have the increment part a bit wrong here. You really only want `p++`, not `*p++`.

```
for (char *p=d; *p; ++p)
   if (*p == '.')
       ++count;
```

When we get down to it, a slightly modified version of that loop is pretty much all we really need for the whole task though:

```
char const *p;
for (p = argv[1]; *p; ++p)
   if (*p == '.')
       ++count;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are counting the number of commas, not of periods. To count periods change the if statement to:

```
if (*p =='.'){
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (*p ==',')
```

to

```
if (*p =='.')
```

to count `.`.

Comment: Sitting in front of a computer for about 14 hrs now learning c, silly mistakes are made. Thanks @haccks

Comment: @ojhawkins It happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is just a typo. Replace ',' with '.' and it will return "4", I've just tested it.